# real time streaming image encoding options

Tags: image-processing, digital-communications, real-time, image-compression

I'm interested in streaming video real time. There is an issue of deciding how to properly encoder the images and the format they should be.

Since the data will be streamed over UDP, it needs to be tolerant to packet loss in so far as creating semi acceptable image even if a portion of packers are dropped.

What is the go-to encoding for image streaming?

Comment: All modern video codecs are somewhat tolerant to packet losses, as you can imagine (even if the video is just to be stored on a bluray, it would be a shame if an error would break the whole video). *I'm interested in streaming video real time* I'm sure you've looked into digital TV, video stream services and videoconferencing codecs then, already! Please ask a more specific question than "what's the go-to", because as even very superficial research would have told you, that depends on parameters like quality, compression and latency needs which you forgo to specify!